# Se produjo una excepción en flutter

Tags: android, flutter, app

estoy creando una app con flutter en la cual puedes seleccionar un estado de la republica mexicana y dependiendo del estado que haya seleccionado mostrara las ciudades de ese estado que selecciono pero al momento de seleccionar otro estado me muestra este mensaje

```
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 939 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1': There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButtonFormField]'s value: 68382. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value)
```

1. tengo un provider que lista todos los estados de la república Mexicana

   `final CountryProvider = Provider.of<ApiCountry>(context);`
2. luego ese `CountryProvider` lo uso en un `DropdownButtonFormField` de esta manera

   ```
   DropdownButtonFormField(
       dropdownColor: Colors.white,
       style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
       onChanged: (value) {
       _value = value!;
       setState(() {
       citiesList = [];
       _getCytiesList();
        });
       },
        items: CountryProvider.DisplayList.map(
               (e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: Text(e.name),
                      value: e.iso2,
                       )).toList(),//aqui termina DropdownMenuItem
                      ),//aqui termina el widget
   ```

en el `setState(){}`uso 3 elementos una es `_value` el cual contiene el `id del estado`, otra que es  `citiesList = [];` la que lista todas las ciudades que pertenezcan al estado que usuario selecciono y luego uso `_getCytiesList();` la que llama a la api para consultar las ciudades del estado que selecciono el usuario

3.Listar las ciudades dependiendo del estado seleccionado

```js
 late String _value;
  List citiesList = [];
  Future _getCytiesList() async {
    final response;
    response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(
            "https://api.countrystatecity.in/v1/countries/MX/states/$_value/cities"),
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'application/json',
          'X-CSCAPI-KEY':
              'QlB0azZPRXV0NVA4S0MwUEdRbkprbGhQQXpyNjM5cmhSVktiWkRHcQ=='
        });
    var data = {'result': json.decode(response.body)};
    setState(() {
      final mapCityJson = BodyCity.fromJson(data);
      citiesList = mapCityJson.result;
    });
  }
```

la variable `late String _value;` es el estado que el cliente selecciono y con ello llamo a la api para que me de todas las ciudades  y esa lista de ciudades las guardo en citiesList

```
BodyCity.fromJson(data); es un modelo que genere con `https://app.quicktype.io/`
```

el detalle es que cuando selecciono otro estado me muestra el error que esta al principio del post `_AssertionError` hasta ahorita se me ocurrio validar si esta vacio o no pero no tuve resultado si alguien puede aconsejarme lo agradeceria mucho, excelente inicio de semana

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo al error:

> There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButtonFormField]'s
> value: 68382.  Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were
> detected with the same value)

y a lo que comentas:

"uso 3 elementos una es _value el cual contiene el id del estado, otra que es  citiesList = []; la que lista todas las ciudades que pertenezcan al estado que usuario selecciono"

este error se produce cuando un elemento (`_value`) no se contiene dentro del array (`citiesList` ).

---

Ejemplo de como puede suceder el error, tienes un arreglo de elementos:

```
var cities =  ['Merida', 'Bucharest', 'Estocolmo','Iasi', 'Mexico City'];
```

pero el elemento que buscaras en el array `cities` no se encuentra entre los elementos.

```
var city ='Guadalajara';
```